# what inference can we draw from an equation which says that sum of two square numbers is zero?

Tags: number-theory

I have an equation $(a-2b)^2 + (b-2c)^2 = 0$ where, $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive real numbers. What will be $a:b:c$?

Comment: What simple inequalities does $x^2$ obey $\forall x$?

Comment: it will always be positive and for x=0, x^2 =0.
okay does it mean a = 2b and b = 2c.?

thank you I understood this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any real number $x$ we have $x^2\ge 0$, thus it follows that $a-2b=b-2c=0.$ Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, Thank you Jack.